# Autofill dates in excel for particular month

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, autofill

i am using excel 2007 and i want to autofill dates of a particular month.

[image]

In above screenshot, i am selecting Month through drop down in cell A48, i want to auto fill dates in cell B51:AF51. For example, if i select May month then dates 1 to 31  and for June dates 1 to 30 should be autofilled.

Answer (score 2):

In b51,

```
=if(month($a48)=month(date($a47, month($a48), column(a:a))), date($a47, month($a48), column(a:a)), text(,))
```

Fill right an additional 30 cells.