# Autofill dates for a Particular Month Vertically

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets

I'm trying to reach this same conclusions as found here

[Autofill dates in excel for particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072994/autofill-dates-in-excel-for-particular-month)

but with the dates vertically down a column. Have played around with autofill and changing the expression a little and am striking out

Basically want this expression able to be filled vertically and still functional.

```
=if(month($a48)=month(date($a47, month($a48), column(a:a))), date($a47, month($a48), column(a:a)), text(,))
```

EDIT: I'm also trying to get it to omit days not in that month. For instance, if I drag this out 30 more days to get all 31 days in July, it will work. But if I change the date later to August, It will then give me all of August and September 1st.

Comment: Change `$a48` to `a$48`, `$a47` to `a$47` and `column(a:a)` to `row(1:1)` and see if that helps.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also go really simple:

[image]

Comment: This is also a great way. The solution I am trying to work towards is one where if I change the first date it will auto-populate all of the days of that month. The problem I'm running into now is that with different numbers of days in the month, its also populating the next day or two of the next month.